# Estoy tratando de agregar una foto en mi registro de usuario usando las clases de Auth que me da LARAVEL

Tags: laravel-6

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function register(Request $request){
   $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
     event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
      $this->guard()->login($user);
      return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath()); }
```

Comment: Lo que quiero realizar es lo siguiente: como tengo la clase Register y esta espera un array de datos quiero agregar el campo fotos y que en ella solo se guarde la url de donde se va a extraer la foto y guardarla en una carpeta.

Comment: Pasa el código de tu imagen a texto por favor

Comment: Los detalles de tu duda deben ir en la pregunta y no en la zona de comentarios, por favor edita y amplia